# Android MySQL issue in Android 4.0 only?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ui-thread

I get this error on my Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0) device and emulator.  But the app runs perfectly on Android 2.3 emulator.

```
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kickinglettuce.rate_this/com.kickinglettuce.rate_this.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:87)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:103)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at com.kickinglettuce.rate_this.Main.onCreate(Main.java:81)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
06-19 00:34:38.357: E/AndroidRuntime(535):  ... 11 more
```

The start-up activity is almost identical to this:

http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/10/android/android-connecting-to-mysql-using-php/

Here is the null line in my code:
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);

Comment: Without seeing your code, its hard to debug from just a stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post this morning on the same topic:

### [Why Does My App Crash On Ice Cream Sandwich?](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

---

The reason you are performing because you are getting a force close is because you are attempting a network connection on the UI thread. This is a potentially expensive operation and will likely block the UI thread causing lag. ICS and HoneyComb introduced stricter checks against abusing the UI thread, and now automatically force closes your app if you attempt doing so. This is why your application crashes on Android 4.0 but not on Android 2.3. You should perform the HTTP request in a separate thread of some sort (i.e. either a plain `Thread` or an `AsyncTask`).

Read my blog post linked above... it goes into more detail why you should be performing such operations in a separate worker thread. You might also find this [sample code](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask) helpful in getting you started.

Comment: When Android force-closes an app, it throws a null-pointer exception?  This doesn't seem very intuitive.

Comment: The `NullPointerException` causes the app to force close, not the other way around.

Comment: I realize a null-pointer exception will cause it to close, but you're saying "ICS and HoneyComb ... force closes your app" -- If thats true, and if that is the case here, why wouldn't they throw a `AbusingUIThreadException` (or whatever) -- why a null-pointer exception that indicates a programming error, not an architectural one.

Comment: See the [`HttpClient`](https://sinaweibo-honeycomb.googlecode.com/svn-history/r69/branches/sinaweibo-merged/src/weibo4andriod/http/HttpClient.java) source code. The `HttpClient` catches a `NetworkOnMainThread` exception in the `httpRequest` method. When the method returns, `Response res` is still set to `null`, so the method returns `null`. In this case, the `NullPointerException` causes the force close instead.

Comment: Wow thanks, the timing on that post was impeccable.  Now I just have to figure out how to use Asyntask...

Comment: Someone else asked a very similar question about 5 hours ago too... I wasn't lying when I said this question "plagues" StackOverflow haha :)